# Webdriver can't find the element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[image: buttons]

Selenium cant find this xpath I tried every way I need to click last button Deactivate but I cant

I tried xpath,cssSelectors,

```
 @When("^I click deactivate button$")
public void iClickDeactivateButton(){
    WebElement deactivateBatchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@_ngcontent-c14=''][text()='Deactivate'][text()='Deactivate']/self::BUTTONclass='deactivate']"));
    deactivateBatchButton.click();
}
```

I want to click this button and carry one rest of the tests.

Answer (score 0):

As the desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element and to locate it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement deactivateBatchButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.deactivate.xh-highlight")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement deactivateBatchButton = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='deactivate xh-highlight' and text()='Deactivate']")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can carry on with the button name.

```
    WebElement deactivateBatchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Deactivate']"));

deactivateBatchButton.click();
```